# Modifying animated jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, animation, menu

I am using this method to create animated menus/background images on my site: [Animated Content Menu with jQuery | Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/03/09/animated-content-menu/)

It is quite easy to use, but my problem is that I want to have multiple pages on the site, and need to figure out how I can modify the menu on the home page so that instead of triggering the submenu and new background image, each `li` will just link to a new page.

I don't know how to remove the submenu animations and background image switch while preserving the slide in/slide out, fade-in on the initial background image and without breaking the code entirely.

Comment: I agree with Thomas Shields answer.....

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the line below and add links to new pages in your `<a>`s

```
 /* user clicks one item : appetizers | main course | desserts | wines | specials */
                       $el_title.bind('click.Menu', function(e) {
                                $.when(toggleMenuItems('down')).done(function(){
                                openSubMenu($item, $sub_menu, el_image);
                            });
                            return false;
                        });
```

Comment: I tried this, and while it removes the background image function, when I add an html file to the `a`s it causes the whole menu to not load.

Comment: @Devonanne hm...i think we're gonna need a link to your page to debug this, if possible.